# SAS boxplot with inner margin

Tags: sas, boxplot

I'm not very experienced in SAS yet. 
My problem is that I need to add number of observations to a boxplot (I'm using proc boxplot). I tried insetgroup option, but I don't like the result, I need something prettier. 
I have found this 
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/wusspaper.pdf

I need something like this, with numbers in the inner margin

[image]
It's great they have code there, but I don't get where are these numbers (No. of subjects at visit) are taken from, if they are calculated separately, where they are in a dataset, etc. It's a pity the initial dataset is not shown.

Any help and any other ideas how to add numbers of patients will be very appreciated.

Comment: as far as i understand, they are from columns tota and totb in the initial dataset and added via the boxplot.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some SAS code where the Ns are added to proc boxplot using annotate.  In general for annotate, you need to be careful about setting up the coordinate system you want, read the documentation regarding annotate and  xsys/ysys for a detailed explaination.

Hope this helps.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=work.class;
    by sex;
run;

*** GET COUNTS FOR EACH GROUP ***;
proc freq data=class;
    tables sex / out=stats;
run;

*** CREATE ANNOTATE DATASET ***;
data anno_stats;
    set stats (drop=percent);

    xsys='2';
    ysys='1';
    position='5';

    function='label';
    text='N=' || strip( put(count, 3.));

    *** X COORDINATE IS THE GROUP VARIBLE IN THE BOXPLOT ***;
    *** USE VARIABLE XC INSTEAD OF X SINCE THIS IS A CHARACTER VARIABLE IN THIS EXAMPLE ***;
    xc=sex;
    *** Y COORDIANTE IS 3% ABOVE X-AXIS, BASED ON YSYS=1 ***;
    y=3;
run;

proc boxplot data=class anno=anno_stats;
    plot height * sex;
run;
```